# Search for text with Regex

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I need a regular expression to get the text out from between `[` and `]` within a sentence.

**Example Text:**

```
Hello World - Test[**This is my string**]. Good bye World.
```

**Desired Result:**

```
**This is my String**
```

---

The regex that I have come up with is `Test\\[[a-zA-Z].+\\]`, but this returns the entire `**Test[This is my string]**`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<=Test\[)[^\[\]]*(?=\])
```

should do what you want.

```
(?<=Test\[) # Assert that "Test[" can be matched before the current position
[^\[\]]*    # Match any number of characters except brackets
(?=\])      # Assert that "]" can be matched after the current position
```

Read up on [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Answer (score 2):

You could use a capturing group to access to the text of interest:

```
\[([^]]+)\]
```

A quick proof of concept using JavaScript:

```
var text = 'Hello World - Test[This is my string]. Good bye World.'
var match = /\[([^\]]+)\]/.exec(text)
if (match) {
  console.log(match[1]) // "This is my string"
}
```

If the regular expression engine you are using supports both [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) and [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind), Tim's solution is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

```
Match m = Regex.Match(@"Hello World - Test[This is my string]. Good bye World.", 
            @"Test\[([a-zA-Z].+)\]");
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
```